# Bootstrap4 with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I followed the [official guide](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38668278/bootstrap-with-rails-5) to no help, can someone shed some light on this? ([source on github](https://github.com/SalahEddin/HowManyDankX))

My Gem file:

```
...
#bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha3.1'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'

source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-tether', '>= 1.1.0'
end
...
```

my application.scss:

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
```

my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DankDist</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and Finally, my index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Scale#index</h1>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
</div>
<p>Hello Worldzz</p>
<p>Find me in app/views/scale/index.html.erb</p>
<%= params[:id] %> <br/>
<%= @id %>

Next Page <%= @page +1 %>

<hr/>
<%= params.inspect %>
```

I ran Bundle, and re-tried `rails s` with no changes, the header doesn't contain any styles.

Comment: You still need your require_tree . in your application.css.scss. Rename scss to css.scss then add /*= require.... */ I forgot the string within. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21643987/3338439

Comment: I followed the post, still doesn't work

Comment: Shouldn't you be using bootstrap-sass?

Comment: it's only needed for Bootstrap2 and 3

Comment: Oh yeah. Hmm then I'm not sure. Haven't checked out bootstrap 4. If nobody answers I'll go try it out tomorrow and let u know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few mistakes

1. ScaleController contains layout false - therefore your stylesheet import in your application.html.erb doesn't work
2. @import 'bootstrap-sprockets'; is not necessary for the Bootstrap 4 gem

Answer (score -2):

in application.js, try to line these two lines as follows, i noticed it worked for me:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```